# Are Hawkeye's glasses special?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, costume, hawkeye

In some of his more recent appearances, Hawkeye sports either glasses or goggles of some sort.

[image: Hawkeye comic glasses 1]

[image: Hawkeye comic glasses 2]

[image: Hawkeye MCU glasses]

In any continuity, is his eyewear special in anyway compared to normal glasses? Or are they just regular, if stylish, sunglasses?

Comment: I'll have to do some research but, I don't think so; AFAIK he doesn't have any special abilities with the glasses that he didn't have with the goofy whole-head mask.

Comment: @KutuluMike Looking badass is the greatest power of all.

Comment: I hope they’re at least polarized, or I have more advanced sunglasses than he does.

Comment: they're better than polarized, they're HD.

Comment: Does he ever wear these in the films or just promotional material? The only time I remember seeing them is when they go their own ways at the end of The Avengers so outside of any combat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I've never heard anything about Hawkeye having special glasses.

To back this up, I engaged in Google-Fu. I found a lot of sites 'hawking' replicas of glasses he wore in the movies, but the only result that actually had anything to do with the character was this particular question.

He's probably just wearing [shooting glasses](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dsporting&field-keywords=shooting%20glasses). Shooting glasses are sunglasses that are polarized to reduce glare and allow the shooter to better focus on their target. They also double as safety glasses to protect the shooter's eyes.

I checked, and shooting glasses are indeed [used in archery](https://www.archery360.com/2014/03/24/shades-top-archers-find-success-pilla-eyewear/). In that article, an employee of a company that makes such glasses says:

> Pilla shades have a calming effect on archers, Milbury believes. “By managing the light properly, archers give their eyes the opportunity to relax. Thus the muscles in their face and neck will be more relaxed, giving them a better and more consistent form when drawing their bow. It’s also a tremendous mental benefit, especially with high-stakes competition. The glasses protect from glaring light, dust, wind and many other distractions, allowing archers to focus better and for longer periods of time.”

Since the Olympics are currently underway, here's an image of this year's Men's Archery Individual gold medalist, Ku Bon-chan of South Korea, wearing what appear to be shooting glasses:

[image: Ku Bon-chan in shades]